# Use same DNS name both as host name and subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system

Can I configure a DNS zone such that both `a.b.c` and `b.c` can serve as host names? In other words, can `b.c` be both a subdomain and a hostname at the same time?

Is this perhaps just a matter of serving both `A` and `NS` (for delegation) records for `b` in `c`'s zone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can! You also do somethhing similar when making `example.com` and `www.example.com` point to an `A` record. You will have to create the `A` record on the delegated zone though.

You can combine `A` and `NS` records but you can’t combine them with a `CNAME` record.

Note that the terms “hostname” and “subdomain” are kinda synonymous as you can create`A` records for `www.test(.example.com.)` and both `wwe` and `test` are considered a subdomain. You’re talking about a delegation of a zone here. And you can both delegate a zone and assign an `A` record to it (from the delegated zone, as its apex).

Answer (score 7):

If you only want to have records for `b.c` and `a.b.c` subdomains are not necessary. It's completely valid to have more sub-levels in one file, for example in zonefile for `c` you can have

```
b    IN     A    127.0.0.1
a.b  IN     A    127.0.0.2
```

If you really want a subdomain  `b.c` first define delegation i `c` zonefile.

```
b    IN     NS   ns.with.b.c.zone
```

the `ns.with.b.c.zone` can point on the same server, or to hosting provider for example. Is good practice to have at least two DNS server for domain. [RFC1912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.8)

next define `A` record for `b.c` in zonefile for `b.c`

```
@    IN     A    127.0.0.2
```

or

```
b.c. IN     A    127.0.0.2
```

Comment: If I understand your example with delegation correctly, the host `b.c` hosts a domain server for the delegated domain `b`. Does this have to be the case or could it be hosted elsewhere?

Comment: It can be hosted everywhere, for example at hosting company.
b IN NS some-ns.somecompany.com.
in this case is not necessary to have following A record